# How to rename List of Figures and List of Tables?

Tags: table-of-contents

How do I rename List of Figures into Figures and List of Tables into Tables? (An automatic function in LaTeX)

```
\listoftables
\listoffigures
```

I used this to create them.

And I'm using

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrreprt}
```

Comment: As you are using KOMA-Script (class `scrreprt`) please see my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83021/16550 Possible duplicate question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you load package `babel`? Then you can rename LoF and LoT using KOMA-Script command `\renewcaptionname`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\listfigurename}{Figures}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\listtablename}{Tables}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, it worked