# Properly change title for listings in classic-thesis?

Tags: classicthesis

Why `\listtablename` gets properly translated (to spanish)

```
\pdfbookmark[1]{\listtablename}{lot}`
```

…. while `\lstlistlistingname`  does not?

```
\pdfbookmark[1]{\lstlistlistingname}{lol}
```

The first line puts 'Lista de Tablas' in the contents of my pdf viewer (evince), the second line puts 'Listings'.

How can I fix this?

I am working on linux (Fedora 32) with version 4.6 of classic-thesis and pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019).

My workaround was to change the first text between braces with something in spanish. This works for almost everything, except for Listings (for example: `\pdfbookmark[1]{Acrónimos}{acronyms}`). To be more explicit, the title in the toc in my pdf viewer changes but not in the main document. Here is the code (from `Contents.tex`)

```
\pdfbookmark[1]{\listtablename}{lot}
\listoftables

\vspace{8ex}
% \newpage

%*******************************************************
% List of Listings
%*******************************************************
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}
\pdfbookmark[1]{\lstlistlistingname}{lol}
\lstlistoflistings

\vspace{8ex}

%*******************************************************
% Acronyms
%*******************************************************
%\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[1]{Acrónimos}{acronyms}
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Acronyms}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Acronyms}}
\chapter*{Acronyms}
```

See the difference between Lista de Tablas, Listings and Acrónimos...

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Try lockstep's answer, or if needed Mensch's answer, at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/. In short, you'll be adding something like `\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand*{\lstlistlistingname}{Lista de}}` to your -config.tex file. Also check https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/wiki/SpanishLanguageSupport.

Comment: That works. But only for Listings. You have to manually change every corresponding `\pdfbookmark` in every file where there is no proper macro name for that particular section/chapter.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness I will specify what I did.

Although I followed the steps outlined in [here](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/wiki/SpanishLanguageSupport) to get spanish support in `classic-thesis`...

- In `classicthesis-config.tex`: `\PassOptionsToPackage{english,spanish,mexico,es-lcroman,es-tabla}{babel} \usepackage{babel}`.
- In `ClassicThesis.tex`: `\selectlanguage{spanish} % español`
- And in `Abstract.tex`: `\begin{otherlanguage}{english}` and the respective `\end{}` before the second abstract.

... It seems that not everything is *translated*.

As PhilipPirrip in the comments says the answer is to `\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand*{\lstlistlistingname}{Algo en español}}`. As pointed out by Ivo Pletikosić in [here](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/issues/180/pdfbookmark-for-listings-to-spanish) that must be added to the file `classicthesis-config.tex`. I added the next lines before the line that starts with `% Fix to getting autorefs for subfigures right`:

```
  \addto\captionsspanish{%
    \renewcommand*{\lstlistlistingname}{Lista de código}%
    \renewcommand*{\lstlistingname}{Código} 
}
```

I also changed almost every `\pdfbookmark[1]{Title in English}{title in english}` to something like `\pdfbookmark[1]{Título en Español}{título en español}`. Here is a list:

```
+ Abstract.tex:\pdfbookmark[1]{Resumen}{Abstract}
+ Abstract.tex:\pdfbookmark[1]{Abstract}{Zusammenfassung}
+ Acknowledgments.tex:\pdfbookmark[1]{Agradecimientos}{acknowledgments}
+ Colophon.tex:\pdfbookmark[0]{Colofón}{colophon}
o Contents.tex:\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}
o Contents.tex:    \pdfbookmark[1]{\listfigurename}{lof}
o Contents.tex:    \pdfbookmark[1]{\listtablename}{lot}
o Contents.tex:    \pdfbookmark[1]{\lstlistlistingname}{lol}
+ Contents.tex:    \pdfbookmark[1]{Acrónimos}{acronyms}
+ Declaration.tex:\pdfbookmark[0]{Declaración de autenticidad}{declaration}
+ Dedication.tex:\pdfbookmark[1]{Dedicatoria}{Dedication}
o DirtyTitlepage.tex:%\pdfbookmark[1]{Titel}{title}
+ Publications.tex:\pdfbookmark[1]{Publicaciones}{publications}
o Titlepage.tex:    %\pdfbookmark[1]{\myTitle}{titlepage}
```

Where the symbol before each line means that there was a change (`+`) or there was not (`o`).

Also you have to change every `\chapter*{Title in English}` to `\chapter*{Título en Español}` like `\chapter*{Agradecimientos}`and etc.

Hope it helps...

Ps. Please correct me if I am wrong, as I am very new to `LaTeX`