# How to change color or remove the default " references" when citing?

Tags: bibliographies

I am new to LaTeX sorry if this is very naive, I have a school project and decided to use this as a chance to learn LaTeX.

[image]

After doing what some YouTube videos told me to, I somehow get a default "references" which I either want to change color or remove and have the citations under bibliography which is already blue

I did not find any related questions here, any way forward?

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,16pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red}} 

\begin{document}

\section*{\color{blue}Bibliography}

~\cite{enwiki:1028348687}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{wiki.bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer depends on how you set up your bibliography (there are several ways to do that in LaTeX) and a few other things. Please show us how you currently generate your bibliography in a small example document that reproduces the output you show in the question with as little unrelated code as possible (often called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @moewe sir/ma'am will my recent edit do?

Comment: You could remove the `\section*{\color{blue}Bibliography}` and add `\renewcommand*{\refname}{\color{blue}Bibliography}` to your preamble.

Comment: @moewe I don't know how it worked but it worked! Could you copy-paste that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the article class the heading of the bibliography is saved in `\refname`. So you could remove the manual `\section*{\color{blue}Bibliography}` and tell LaTeX to typeset the heading as you like by redefining `\refname` with `\renewcommand*{\refname}{\color{blue}Bibliography}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,16pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red}} 

\renewcommand*{\refname}{\color{blue}Bibliography}

\begin{document}
\cite{enwiki:1028348687}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{wiki}
\end{document}
```

Note that you may need additional code when you use a localisation package like `babel` or `polyglossia`. See [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography", "Appendix", etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/35864).

Note that `report`- and `book`-based classes generally use `\bibname` where `article`-based classes usually use `\refname`.