# How to change the name Figure to greek Εικόνα

Tags: babel-greek

I would like to change the name "Σχήμα" to "Εικόνα" as you can see in the screenshot. Without babel it would be easy since I change the document element Figure to other word. How can I do it in babel. I tried `\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Εικόνα.}`. But it can not do it. My code is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{figure}[H]

\includegraphics[width=20cm]{PictureA.jpg}

\centering \selectlanguage{greek}

\caption{Αρχική κατάσταση. Μετωπιαία όψη.}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Untested, but for Greek you would expect something like `\addto\captionsgreek{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Εικόνα.}}` and not `\captionsenglish`.

Comment: ...I can even think why I was trying with captionsenglish..thank you

Comment: This is the same with the listfigures?\addto\captionsgreek{\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{Κατάλογος Εικόνων}}

Comment: `\listoffigures` is the entire command that prints the list of figures. `\listfigurename` is the heading that you get from `\listoffigures`. See the list in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/35864.

Comment: \def\figurename{...} should handle both the \caption and LOF, but you have to make the change AFTER babel does it (\AtBeginDocument?).

Comment: @JohnKormylo In multilingual documents redefining captions with `\AtBeginDocument` is not correct, because the default string is restored when the language is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (≥ [3.51](https://latex3.github.io/babel/news/whats-new-in-babel-3.51.html)) the best option is `\setlocalecaption`, as shown:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\setlocalecaption{greek}{figure}{Εικόνα}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=20cm]{PictureA.jpg}
\centering \selectlanguage{greek}
\caption{Αρχική κατάσταση. Μετωπιαία όψη.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This generates the following caption:
[image]