# I need to change the title References to Références bibliographiques because my document has to be in French

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

[image: 1]

How can I change the bibliography title

I also want to know why there are numbers under
1 Références bibliographiques

Comment: As to your second question, it is the citation symbol with the link to the bibliography as you can often see in academic papers. It would be better if you check out more LaTeX  documentation or tutorial.

Comment: It does but nothing is working for me here

Comment: Maybe you can **EDIT** your question to provide a **minimum working example (MWE)** that can be compiled for us to test. Some codes can interfere with each other.

Comment: Please never post images of code. Always post code as copy-and-pasteable text (marked up as code) in the question. Code in images is a pain to copy and a serious accessibility issue for people who rely in screen readers. Please also consider posting fully compilable example documents. Snippets of code are often not enough to tell what is going on (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6255/35864).

Comment: But now to your question: If you load a the language package `babel` and tell it that you want a French document, all document elements should automatically be translated into French. It is not a good idea to try to translate all bits manually yourself. Additionally, `\bibliography` already comes with its own bibliography heading. You should not typeset another heading yourself with `\section{Références}`. The numbers appear, because you explicitly `\cite`d two entries at that point. If you want to add entries to the bibliography without an explicit `\cite`, use `\nocite`.

Comment: If you use `biblatex`, you can code ìn your preamble `\DefineBibliographyStrings{bibliography = {Références bibliographiques}}`.

Comment: @Bernard Do I need to change the cmd to show the bibliography or not? (`\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Bibliographie.bib}`)

Comment: These are the package I use `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor, diagbox, empheq, makecell, tcolorbox}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, linguex, enumitem, amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[skip=\baselineskip]{parskip}
\pagestyle{empty}`

Comment: and this is the code line i use to show the bibliography `\nocite{mukundan2002quaternions}
\nocite{conlan2017blender}
\nocite{dam1998quaternions}
\nocite{fenn2006managing}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Bibliographie.bib}`

Comment: @Mrquaternions; The syntax of `vivlatex` si slightly different from the usual  one. You have to declare the ..bib files with `\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}` in the preamble, and `\printbibliography` where you want it in the body of the document.

Comment: To make your document more French a first step would be to turn `\usepackage[english]{babel}` into `\usepackage[french]{babel}`. If you are still not happy with some of the titles you see, follow the accepted answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/35864 in the "With `babel`" section.