# Changing biblatex title

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

this seems quite simple, but the standard solution that I can find online, does not work.

So I have this really simple document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{demo}

\author{asse }

\date{August 2022}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{main.bib}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

hi my name is \cite{LoraAllicance}

\newpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and currently, when i print the bibliography, the title above it, is "References" and I want it to be "Bibliography", which I think is more academic.

When I googled this, adding this to the preamble seems like the standard solution:

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}
```

But this has no effect.

What to do?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}` is the command for the older package `bibtex`. Since you are using `biblatex`, you need `\printbibliography[title = Bibliography]`.

Answer (score 5):

For the title of the bibliography list, most LaTeX bibliography implementations differentiate between `article`-like and `report`/`book`-like classes. For the former, the title of the bibliography is "References" (stored in `\refname`), for the latter it's "bibliography" (stored in `\bibname`).

Internally, `biblatex` uses also uses `\refname` and `\bibname`, but you can't redefine those commands directly, since their contents are overwritten by `biblatex`'s bibliography strings. (It's similar if you load `babel`. Definitions in the preamble are overwritten by `babel`'s language initialisation. You'd need to use `\appto\captions<language>`, see [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography", "Appendix", etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/35864.)) The `biblatex` way of redefining `\refname` is to redefine the bibstring `references`. Analogously you redefine `\bibname` by redefining the bibstring `bibliography`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  references = {Bibliography},
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Lorem \cite{sigfridsson}

\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Bibliography" as heading for bibliography]

For a one-off change you can also use `\printbibliography`'s `title` argument

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Lorem \cite{sigfridsson}

\newpage
\printbibliography[title=Whatever you want]
\end{document}
```

[image: "Whatever you want" as heading for bibliography]

---

If you always manually force a `\newpage` before a new `\section` (like you did in the example before `\printbibliography`) that suggests you might want to look into a document class with actual chapters that start on new pages automatically. In that case you'd be looking at `report`-like classes where the bibliography heading is automatically "Bibliography". Note that the `report`s have `\chapter`s as the higher-level heading.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
Lorem \cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Bibliography" as heading for bibliography, but this time as chapter heading, so slightly more bombastic]